# getElementbyID with external js file, return null hust for one specific id

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I really can't get rid of this problem with my web application.

I have a list of IDds I pass to my function in js, every of them ar correctly passed to my function except one:

HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/mystyle.css" />
<script src="JS/utils.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
<script src="JS/albumManagement.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script>
<!-- <script src="sort.js" charset="utf-8" defer></script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <div align="right">
        <a href="Logout">Logout</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Welcome to the Images Gallery Home Page</h1>
    <p>Nice to see you again <span id="id_username"></span></p>
    <div id="id_alert" class="alertmessage"></div>  


    <div id = "imagDaMostrare"> </div>  <!-- THIS TAG RETURNS NULL -->
        
    
    
<table ><!--esterna1-->
    <tr>
        <td > <!--blocco1 ALBUM-->
            <div class = "centered"> ALBUM<!--div1-->
            
                <table id = "id_interna1">  <!--interna1-->

                    <thead >
                    <tr >
                        <th>
                            Title
                        </th>
                        <th >
                            Date
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    
                   
     
                </table>
            </div>
        
        </td>
        
        <td>  <!--blocco2 IMMAGINI-->

                
                <table id = "id_interna2SELECTED"> <!--interna2-->
          
                <!--    <tr>                
                        <td>IMG1</td>
                        <td>IMG2</td>
                        <td>IMG3</td>
                        <td>IMG4</td>
                        <td>IMG5</td>
                   </tr>--> 
                                
               
                   
                </table>
               

                
            

                
            </div>
        
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>



    
    
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JS where i load the page, call start and refresh function of PageOrchestrator. In the start I initialize the AlbumDetails passing the IDs needed, but one of those returns null.

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
      pageOrchestrator.start(); // initialize the components
      pageOrchestrator.refresh();
     // display initial content
  }, false);

function PageOrchestrator() {
             var alertContainer = document.getElementById("id_alert");
            
             
        /////////////Page Orchestrator START////////
             this.start = function() {
                 var usrn = sessionStorage.getItem('username');
                 
                 //personal message (in START Page Orchestrator)
                  personalMessage = new PersonalMessage(sessionStorage.getItem('username'),
                    document.getElementById("id_username"));
                  personalMessage.show();
                  
                  
                  //albumList message (in START Page Orchestrator)
                    albumsList = new AlbumsList(alertContainer,
                        document.getElementById("id_interna1"),
                        document.getElementById("id_interna2SELECTED"));
                      
                    
                  //albumList message (in START Page Orchestrator)
                    albumDetails = new AlbumDetails(
                    document.getElementById("id_interna2SELECTED"),
                    document.getElementById("imagDaMostrare"));   //THE ID THAT RETURNS NULL
                    
                    
            
                    
                  //imageDetails message (in START Page Orchestrator)
                    imageDetails = new ImageDetails(alertContainer,
                            document.getElementById("imagDaMostrare"));
                    
                    console.log("1) chiamata imagedetaila new()");
                    
             };
             
        /////////////Page Orchestrator REFRESH//////// 
             this.refresh = function(currentAlbum) {
                  alertContainer.textContent = "";
                  albumsList.reset();
                  albumDetails.reset();
                  imageDetails.reset();
                  
                 
                  albumsList.show(); // closure preserves visibility of this
               //   wizard.reset();
                 
                };
                
    
            
             
             
        }



function AlbumDetails ( _interna2Selected,  _imagDaMostrare) {
            
            
            this.interna2Selected= _interna2Selected;
            
            this.imagDaMostrare = _imagDaMostrare;
            
            
//TESTING NULLITY
                console.log("NULLITY TEST 1 : "+this.interna2Selected); //RETURNS [object HTMLTableElement]
                console.log("NULLITY TEST 2: "+this.imagDaMostrare); // RETURNS NULL
```

I really can't get why just on of those IDs returns null..I Hope somebody can help me.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure your code works? Are you sure your code works? You obviously have one extra parenthesis at the beginning // display initial content  } <- here ?

Comment: that was from an "else" statment i removed to simplify the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, i renamed the id as follow

```
<div id = "id_imagDaMostrare"> </div>
```

instead of

```
<div id = "imagDaMostrare"> </div>
```